# Is there a simple way to add paging to ListViewByQuery ?

Tags: 2010, list-view, spquery

I'm working with a ListViewQuery component on a webpart and I need to add paging control to it.

Is there a simple way to achieve that ?

I saw somewhere than just setting the RowLimit property of the SPQuery should work, but on my case, it didn't change anything at all.

If there is no simple way, I will implement paging myself by creating a custom component, but it will be better if something integrated exists.